# scrollable dialog in jquery

Tags: jquery, dialog

i am trying to replicate "DEMO 3" in this page:

http://www.mudaimemo.com/p/simpledialog/

it works great except that i am filling up the checkbox list dynamically and sometimes i have more checkboxes than fit on the page.  is there anyway to make this scrollable so there is a max size as right now it just goes off the screen.

EDIT:
when i try to add a height to the javascript, the box comes up the right height but the checkboxes keep going down the page.  how do i keep the checkboxes in the container and have a vertical scroll bar?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sdHc3').simpleDialog({
    showCloseLabel: false,
        height: 400,
        open: function() {
            $('#checkboxStatus').html('');
        },
        close: function() {
            var c = [];
            $('#checkboxForm :checkbox:checked').each(function() {
                c.push($(this).val());
            });
            $('#checkboxStatus').html('&nbsp;&nbsp;Checked <b>' + c.join(', ') + '</b>.').show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Set a fixed hight and set the overflow to scroll for the container div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

overflow: scroll;

in the css for the container div, make sure you set a height. Trouble with this is that not all browsers support max-height and so your div will always be the same size (ofc unless you specify each time you need this feature, a different height)

In your css file (in this case do it in the css file: jquery.simpledialog.0.1.css if you didn't rename the downloaded file):

```
.sd_container{
 font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
 margin:0;
 padding: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #fff;
 border: solid 1px #ccc;
 text-align:center;
 **overflow: scroll;**
}
```

(without the stars ofc)

Comment: how do i force a scroll bar, as per the edit above, setting the height fixes the container box but the checkboxes keep going . .

Comment: what's with all the vote downs?
You need to add the css overflow:scroll;

which isn't in your edit. :)

Comment: **height: 400,** I'm not sure why you have the stars there... that's prob just me... but:
**overflow: scroll,**

Comment: the star were trying to highlight this row in bold but looks like SO doesn't support code that is bold.  i fixed this.

Comment: overflow is for CSS, for whatever the container div is, assign that property for it.

BTW Did you vote me down for my answer?

Comment: Thanks! I was right all along hehe, glad I managed to sort you out buddy.

Comment: use "overflow-y: scroll", if you want a vertical scrollbar only, not both ways.

Answer (score 3):

CSS:

```
#scrollableDiv
{
    overflow: auto;
    height: 549px;/* IE is dumb */
    max-height: 549px;/* Or the amount of pixels you want */
}
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to do anything in firefox